# input data to the 2-d array how this work?

Tags: c++

```
 char board[5][6];

 for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
 cin >> board[i];


 URLPM
 XPRET
 GIAET
 XTNZY
 XOQRS
```

Why do they use only one variable `board[i]` not instead `board` `boardp[i][i]`? 
I do not understand how this works.

And if I do:

```
 cout << board[4]
```

It shows:

```
 XTNZY
 XOQRS
```

All the output below line 4...
I did not understand the procedure for this grammar.

Comment: This is very sloppy code. `border[i]` evaluates to a `char` array, or a `char *`, which is passed to `operator>>`. As the input consists of exactly five characters, `operator>>` writes it, and the trailing '\0', into the six-valued `char` array (since `border`'s 2nd dimension contains 6 characters). That's the only reason this house of cards works.

Comment: I run your code on `clang version 3.8.0` and it prints `XOQRS` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++, a string can be represented in an array of char, and it should be null-terminated characters.

To store "abcd", for example, you need a char array with size of 5(including null character).

```
char str[5];    // store 4 characters => a, b, c, d, \0
```

When you declare the following 2-dimensional array, you make an array of 5 'char[6]'. And the reserved memory is not initialized(since it's local variable), but in your case there are 0's, which is considered as null.

```
char board[5][6];
```

So if you put 5-length characters in board[i], you will have null-terminated characters though it's not a good practice. But if you put 6-length characters in board[i], your string will be connected to the string stored in board[i+1] because there is no end of the string(null). If try to print board[i] with cout or printf(), it will display board[i] and board[i+1] since they print sequence of char's until facing null.

Comment: `And it's initialized with 0` : I don't know about C++ standard, but on C variables are not default initialized.